# Submit button is not working in phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I wrote the code for login page,when i am running on desktop using phonegap desktop it working perfectly,but while i build that using phonegap build and when i tried to open in my phone the submit button is not working.Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
});
function btnclick(){
debugger;
$.ajax({ 
type:"GET",
url: url/"+$('#useName').val()+"/"+$('#Password').val(),
contentType: "application/javascript",
jsonpCallback: "Login",
dataType: "jsonp", //Expected data format from server
});     
}
function Login(data)     
{
if(data==true)
{
window.location.assign("home.html");
}
else{
$('#error').show();
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

And for giving input:

```
<form>
<input id="useName" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" />
<input id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password"  />
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btnclick" onclick="btnclick()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of that is causing you troubles is the whitelist configuration needed for navigating external sources.

you should add on your config.xml something like:

```
<access origin = "*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
```

you can modify them to fit your needs but do try it out fist with a global access to verify that this is your problem.

Also add the cordova whitelist plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"  version="1.0.0"/>
```